# No logout button on togglz console

Tags: togglz

The togglz console has no logout button. Is it possible to add one?

context: I have an api secured with keycloak, i've added togglz console, which means i had to create a separate securityconfig with an order prior to keycloak's config.

TogglzSecurityConfig a simple inmemoryAuthentication ORDER(1)
KeycloakSecurityConfig ORDER(2)

Everything is working fine but once i'm connected to the console, there is no way to logout.